# Get information from service in create dialog Umbraco 7

Tags: c#, web-services, data-binding, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to find out how to put info from web service in umbraco create dialog.

I have trips project and i get my destinations from external web service,
i want to allow the user to select a destination from the web service answer list when adding new trip. (i need to call the web service from CB)

How i can call to a web service before the create dialog shows ? how to put the web service answer (json) in umbraco editor ? 
Which editor to use?

Thanks in advance for all helpers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to have the destination as a property of the destinations document type, I'd make a custom property editor that calls the web service and provides a dropdown on the page editor, rather than doing it before you create the the page.

You can create a custom property editor using Angular and the Umbraco API. There's an example of creating a custom property editor here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/tutorials/Creating-a-Property-Editor/